# How to COPY library files between stages of a multi-stage Docker build while preserving symlinks?

Tags: c++, docker, shared-libraries, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a Dockerfile which is split into a two-stage multi-stage docker build.  The first stage generates a basic gcc build environment in which a number of C and C++ library are compiled.  The second stage uses the `COPY --from=` command to copy the library files from the first stages `/usr/local/lib/libproto*` to the current image's.

The problem I am seeing is that the first image contains symlinks from a generic library file name to a specific versioned file name.  AFAIK this is common practice within Debian and many other Linux systems.  Docker's `COPY` command does not seem to understand symlinks so instead makes two complete copies of the library files.  This results in a larger Docker Image size and warnings from later `apt-get` commands to the tune of `ldconfig: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so.17 is not a symbolic link`.

---

My specific file presently looks like:

```
#Compile any tools we cannot install from packages
FROM gcc:7 as builder
USER 0
RUN \
  apt-get -y update && \
  apt-get -y install \
    clang \
    libc++-dev \
    libgflags-dev \
    libgtest-dev
RUN \
  # Protocol Buffer & gRPC
  # install protobuf first, then grpc
  git clone -b $(curl -L https://grpc.io/release) \
      https://github.com/grpc/grpc /var/local/git/grpc && \
    cd /var/local/git/grpc && \
    git submodule update --init && \
    echo "--- installing protobuf ---" && \
    cd third_party/protobuf && \
    ./autogen.sh && ./configure --enable-shared && \
    make -j$(nproc) && make install && make clean && ldconfig && \
    echo "--- installing grpc ---" && \
    cd /var/local/git/grpc && \
    make -j$(nproc) && make install && make clean && ldconfig


FROM debian
LABEL \
 Description="Basic Debian production environment with a number of libraries configured" \
 MAINTAINER="Mr Me"
ARG prefix=/usr/local
ARG binPath=$prefix/bin
ARG libPath=$prefix/lib
# Copy over pre-made tools
# Protocol Buffer
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/libproto* $libPath/
# gRPC
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/libaddress_sorting.so.6.0.0 $libPath/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/libgpr* $libPath/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/libgrpc* $libPath/
RUN ldconfig
# Install remaining tools using apt-get
RUN apt-get -y update && \
  apt-get -y install \
    libhdf5-dev \
    libssl1.1 \
    uuid-dev;
```

As you can see I am trying to add the latest versions of gRPC and Protocol Buffer to a Debian based runtime image.

Comment: As a workaround you could tar the files, copy the tarball and then untar them in the second container. This would preserve links.

Comment: @JacobTomlinson it is a clunky answer but what you are suggesting could be the only answer.  Please, could you give it in the form of an answer?

Comment: It is so clunky I didn't feel like I should XD. I will do now at your request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than an answer.

You could tar the files, copy the tarball to the second container and then untar them.

Tar [maintains symbolic links](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/dereference.html) by default.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it is the path I ended up taking.  It looks like the Docker system may be updated in the future to handle Symbolic Links natively but until that time this is the best solution.

Comment: @TafT Did you encounter any problems like the ones I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001290/linker-in-second-docker-layer-doesnt-find-shared-opencv-libraries-built-in-prev)? I can't get it to run this way unfortunately.

Comment: @FlorianBlume it is a bit long ago for me to say for sure.  I took a look and might have spotted an issue on the question you link to though.