# Linker in second Docker layer doesn't find shared OpenCV libraries built in previous layer, but files exist

Tags: c++, linux, docker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a docker image with OpenCV 4.3 and my own C++ program linked against OpenCV, both built for Linux. Because building OpenCV takes quite a while and the resulting docker image is pretty large and I only need `libopencv_core.so` and `libopencv_calib3d.so`, I tried to create the following **two layers**:

1. Build OpenCV from source and build my own C++ program that links against OpenCV
2. Copy the shared OpenCV libraries and my compiled program created in the first build layer to the second layer and execute my program

Unfortunately, the linker outputs

```
error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.4.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Adding

```
RUN ls /usr/local/lib
```

in the second layer just before the command to execute my program shows that I successfully copied the built library files:

```
libopencv_calib3d.so
libopencv_calib3d.so.4.3
libopencv_calib3d.so.4.3.0
libopencv_core.so
libopencv_core.so.4.3
libopencv_core.so.4.3.0
```

I already tried these statements to make the libraries visible:

```
RUN ldconfig /usr/local/lib
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib"
RUN ldconfig -v
```

where `ldconfig -v` prints (among other things):

```
/usr/local/lib:
libopencv_calib3d.so.4.3 -> libopencv_calib3d.so.4.3.0
libopencv_core.so.4.3 -> libopencv_core.so.4.3.0
```

I was a bit confused because `ldconfig` didn't list `libopencv_calib3d.so`, that's why I tried create a simlink manually but it complained that `libopencv_calib3d.so` already exists. So it seems that everything is there to run my program. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

---

---

**Appendix**

This is the Dockerfile that I'm using (reduced to the important parts):

```
FROM vookimedlo/ubuntu-clang:clang_bionic AS builder

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update & ...

ARG libPath=/usr/local/lib

# Install OpenCV
RUN git clone & cmake & make install
    tar -czvf ${libPath}/opencv.tar.gz /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.* /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.*

# Download and build my program
...

FROM ubuntu AS runtime

ARG libPath=/usr/local/lib

# Copy compiled libraries
COPY --from=builder ${libPath}/opencv.tar.gz ${libPath}/opencv.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf ${libPath}/opencv.tar.gz -C / && rm ${libPath}/opencv.tar.gz

# Copy my program
...

RUN ldconfig /usr/local/lib
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib"
RUN ldconfig -v

# Run my program
CMD ...
```

Comment: `.so.4.*` This will not get the .so.4 file, only the .so.4.<something> files.  Could you provide a long list of `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libopencv_*` from the generated system to confirm.  I suspect what is happening is a .so -> .so.4 -> so.4-> .so.4.3 -> .so.4.3.0 link chain is missing a link.

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid for not seeing this, your suggestion was right! It works with `.so.4*`. Care to post the answer so I can accept it? After all you solved it ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is always easier for a fresh pair of eyes to spot an issue, especially if those eyes belong to someone that has made very similar mistakes often in the recent past.  No need to feel stupid :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OPs post they mention using `.so.4.*` This will not get the .so.4 file, only the .so.4. files.  I suspect what is happening is a .so -> .so.4 -> so.4-> .so.4.3 -> .so.4.3.0 link chain is missing a link.

To solve this the following lines:

```
# Install OpenCV
RUN git clone & cmake & make install
    tar -czvf ${libPath}/opencv.tar.gz /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.* /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.*
```

Should be updated to:

```
# Install OpenCV
RUN git clone & cmake & make install
    tar -czvf ${libPath}/opencv.tar.gz \
             /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so* \ 
             /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so*
```

(Line breaks and \ only added to make it easier to read for some)

A long list of ls -l /usr/local/lib/libopencv_* from the generated system to confirm.